# How to implement responsive font size in rem - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, responsive-design, font-size

I am using bootstrap 3 in my project and I see that there are 2 declarations of font-size in bootstrap as below:

**Scaffolding.less**

```
html { font-size:10px;}

body{ font-size : @font-base-size; }
```

And the @font-base-size is defined as 14px in variables.less

I have been reading stuff where one way of having responsive font size was to have base font size as px defined in body or html as then use font sizes in **rem** for different components in body such as p, h1 etc.

But I am not sure, where do I define the base font, should it be in html OR body?

And why does bootstrap has different font size in html and body?

**My observations:**
When I define some font size in px in html, then only rem thing works for everything, defining font size as px in body doesn't work with rem.

Comment: My big quibble with this argument is that when adjusting font size and spacing at responsive breakpoints you can set a new font size on the html element and every measurement you've set in rem will automatically adjust, while with px you'll need to write new rules for every measurement you'd like to tweak. Of course more adjustments will probably be needed even when using rem, but with clever planning you get a huge amount of proportional scaling for free. Tying certain box spacing measurements to type, lighter code, and less complexity/ more maintainability equals a clear win for rem to me.

Comment: @Jinu - I am doing the same. Sorry, if there was any confusion. My intent is to have a pixel font size on html OR body ( whatever works) and define the rest in all using rem units. The doubt I have is that why does defining base font size (in pixel) in body doesn't work, while doing it in html does work. And why does bootstrap is having separate font sizes in html and body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rem` unit is relative to the root, or the `html` element.
Thus defining the base font size should happen on the `html` element.

Defining a `font-size` on the `body` will work, but all child elements which have a `font-size` definition using `rem` units will fall back to the root/`html` element to calculate their absolute size.

So:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.parent {
  /* font-size will be 15px here */
}

.parent .child {
  font-size: 1.2rem; /* resolved to 12px */
}
```

As to why Bootstrap uses 2 font-sizes: the `10px` font-size on the `html` element is just part of some global reset they use. Also, some margins/paddings are calculated using the base font size, so it's best not to interfere with that too much.

Comment: Thanks, that's the info I was looking for. So it means, i can safely set the font size on html and then use rem throughout and will change the html font size in media queries, when used for other sized screens.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't set the font size anywhere on the page, then it is the browser default, which is probably `16px.` So, by default `1rem = 16px`, and `2rem = 32px`. If you set a font-size of `20px` on the body element, then `1rem = 20px` and `2rem = 40px.`

In addition, `em`, `rem` are not an absolute unit - it is a unit that is relative to the currently chosen font size. Unless you have overridden font style by setting your font size with an absolute unit (such as `px` or `pt`), this will be affected by the choice of fonts in the user's browser or OS if they have made one, so it does not make sense to use em as a general unit of length except where you specifically want it to scale as the font size scales.

NB: too long for a comment. sorry for that

Comment: "If you set a font-size of 20px on the body element, then 1rem = 20px and 2rem = 40px."   Are you sure about it, because I think rem will not take body element font size as base, it will take the one in html.  

And, em is relative to the font size defined on that element, where as rem is with respect to root.

Comment: Sorry it was mistake. confused with em. yes. you are right. rem depends on the html(root).