# Why using percentage to set default html font-size on mobile devices causes problems

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    html{font-size:6px;}
    #chart h4{font-size:1.3rem;}
    #icon{right:4.2rem;top:17rem;}
    #drag{top:2.6rem;}
    #footer .footer_wrapper{max-width:114rem;margin:0 2%;padding:3rem 0;}
    #footer .copyright{width:20rem;text-align:center;}
}
```

I am learning how to create responsive web pages recently, and I just found that when I use percentages to set default font-size for the root element, problems occurs. Please have a look at the code above, I set the font-size of root element to 6px which works just fine, but if I set it to a percentage like 40%, the 'rem's will work in a very weird way on mobile devices. anyone has any ideas about that please?

Answer (score 0):

The rem unit is relative to the root, or the html element. Thus defining the base font size should happen on the html element.

Defining a font-size on the body will work, but all child elements which have a font-size definition using rem units will fall back to the root/html element to calculate their absolute size.

so

```
    html {
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    body {
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .parent {
      /* font-size will be 15px here */
    }

    .parent .child {
      font-size: 1.2rem; /* resolved to 12px */
    }
```

Referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284870/how-to-implement-responsive-font-size-in-rem-bootstrap)

Comment: Yes I know this, but the question is, I set the font-size of root element using percentages and it doesn't work the right way on mobile devices while it works just fine on PC. For example: html{}

Comment: it works by doing this: html{font-size:6px;} ..................but it doesn't work by doing this: html{font-size:40%} on mobile devices

Comment: Desktop uses default font size which is provided by system or machine we are on if we do not set font size and use percentage, but in case of mobile it will take mobile's font size of 40% which might be text-scaling thing again

Comment: Yes you are right, but the 'rem's work in a real weird way, like some of the contents are scaled while some are not, how could that happen, all parts of the page are supposed to be scaled synchronously, isn't it? I think there must be other reasons.